# Small pocket-sized receipt scanner

Tags: scanner, portable

I am looking for pocket-size scanner to scan the receipts. By receipts I mean these which are printed on thermochromic paper rolls on point-of-sale places.

I understand you can use smart phone plus some apps, but here are the main disadvantages which I've found:

- some point-of-sale receipts are too long to take a picture of it,
- it's difficult to find the right angle (especially when you're on the go whole day),
- it takes too much time of readjusting the camera to catch the focus and not to crop anything,
- default lossy compression format (designed for pictures) gives later trouble for OCR,
- scanned receipts are crooked and creased (not flatten),
- at the end of the day it's difficult to separate receipts from the pictures (I know there are some useful apps for that such as [Expensify](https://www.expensify.com/) or [Evernote](https://evernote.com/), but I didn't find them so convenient, plus what was already said above),
- and so on.

Therefore I am looking for a device which is specially designed for that job to make it this task very simple. Especially on the move, so I could throw away the receipt after successful scan. Otherwise text printed on thermochromic paper is very unstable and it's easily get lost (especially some small text such as dates).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Planon SS100](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16838124011) is the only truly portable scanner I could find.

[image]

- You can scan up to 600 images before having to dump them onto your computer via USB
- Charges over USB
- Monochrome or color scans
- Includes software for organization and OCR

One little downfall which you probably won't care about is that it can't scan wide documents like 8.5x11" paper. It's great for receipts, IDs, or other small things.

Comment: the provided link is out of stock - any alternative available now?

Answer (score 4):

It's not pocket sized, but it is portable: [NeatReceipts](https://www.neat.com/products/premium-bundles/). The scanner is 10.8"W x 1.6"D x 1.3"H and weighs less than a pound, allowing it to scan full sheets of paper.

[image: Product image in hands]

Other features:

- Scans in color, grayscale or black and white
- Optical Character Recognition (OCR) + Intelligent Text Recognition (ITR)
- Can scan 3-4 receipts per minute
- Software runs on OS X and Windows
- Software can send data to Excel, Turbo Tax, Quickbooks, Outlook, and export to JPG format, PDF and more